# why timeout did not work in an asyncClient?

Tags: httpx

I create a asyncClient by `async with httpx.AsyncClient(proxies=proxies,timeout=2.0)as client:`
then I send a request

```
print("get cookie res start", f'xid{xid}')  
cookieres = await client.get(url, headers=headers)  
print("get cookie res ",f'xid{xid}',t-time.time())
```

sometimes the requests will cost more than 2s

```
get cookie res xid0 -4.54197096824646
```

and sometimes I have to wait several minutes and get an error like httpx.readError

Comment: Same here, it just blocks forever for some connections.